# Is it possible to make Bitly preserve encoded query parameters?

Tags: api, bitly

I'm using Bitly to shorten some URLs (which I have no control over), and the URLs are formatted like:
`http://example.net?someParam=abc%2Fdef`

Unfortunately, when I pass that URL to Bitly, the `%2F` gets URL decoded back to a `/`. I've checked through the documentation and I can't see any setting to preserve the encoding.

I've also tried encoding the `%` as `%25` first, but Bitly seems to be selective in which encoded characters to decode - the `%25` remains encoded.

Any ideas how to get around this or whether it's something Bitly can support?

Using this endpoint btw: https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten